# How can I make only the <a> tag clickable not the entire list item clickable in an un-ordered list?

Tags: html, css

I just want the text to be clickable not the entire list item block.

```
<a class="menu_head">Hello</a>

<ul class="menu_body">
<li><a href="#">Sub-menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-menu 2</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Sub-menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-menu 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-menu 5</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Sub-menu 6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-menu 7</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share your css so people can get a clearer picture of your setup

Comment: Is it not already done in your example?

Comment: better still create a JSFiddle showing the issue on live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: if you have this in you css: `a{display: block;}`, that would be your culprit.

Comment: Here's a saved js fiddle with your html, please add your CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/ktRx6/, re-save it then add link to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your css

```
a {display:inline-block;}
```